# Hive on JSON File

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, hive, ccd

I need help in parsing the JSON file using HIVE. This file has nested arrays, when i tried to parse the file or query using the HiVE UDF i can drill down just to one level. Then next level arrays were coming up Null in my result. I have given the example below. File has couple of sections (array ), but below given one is most complex one. I tried to use get_json_object to parse, i was able to get data just one level, it didn't pull the nested arrays at all. It would be helpful if someone guide me in parsing the nested json arrays

```
"section": {
                        "moodCode": "xxx",
                        "classCode": "xxx",
                        "templateId": {
                            "root": "2.xx.840"
                        },
                        "code": {
                            "codeSystemName": "LOINC",

                        },
                        "title": "problems",
                        "text": {
                            "mediaType": "text/x-hl7-text+xml",
                            "list": [{
                                "caption": "Recorded",
                                "item": {
                                    "ID": "pr101",
                                    "content": [{
                                        "ID": "pr101-desc",
                                        "text": "Salm"
                                    },
                                    "003.1"],
                                    "text": "                                              "
                                },
                                "text": "                                        "
                            },
                            {
                                "caption": "Reported",
                                "item": "None Reported",
                                "text": "                                        "
                            }],
                            "text": "                                  "
                        },
                        "entry": {
                            "typeCode": "DRIV",
                            "act": {
                                "moodCode": "EVN",
                                "classCode": "ACT",
                                "templateId": [{
                                    "root": "2.16.840.1.0.1.27"
                                },
                                {
                                    "root": "1.3.6.1.4..1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "root": "1.3.6.1.4.4.5.2"
                                }],
                                "id": {
                                    "root": "068fd4d4-dfa2-48190768f"
                                },
                                "code": {
                                    "nullFlavor": "NA"
                                },
                                "statusCode": {
                                    "code": "completed"
                                },
                                "effectiveTime": {
                                    "low": {
                                        "value": "20140428144743+0100"
                                    },
                                    "high": {
                                        "value": "20140428144743+0100"
                                    },
                                    "text": "                                              "
                                },
                                "entryRelationship": {
                                    "typeCode": "SUBJ",
                                    "observation": {
                                        "moodCode": "EVN",
                                        "classCode": "OBS",
                                        "templateId": [{
                                            "root": "2.16.840.1.20.1.28"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "root": "1.3.6.1.4.1.5.3.1.4.5"
                                        }],
                                        "id": {
                                            "root": "fa34b4da4dbb-b090-01bd4d6ef62b"
                                        },
                                        "code": {
                                            "codeSystemName": "SNOMED CT",
                                            "code": "282009",
                                            "displayName": "diagnosis",
                                            "codeSystem": "2.16.840.1.6.96"
                                        },
                                        "text": {
                                            "reference": {
                                                "value": "#pr101"
                                            },
                                            "text": "                                      "
                                        },
                                        "statusCode": {
                                            "code": "completed"
                                        },
                                        "effectiveTime": {
                                            "low": {
                                                "value": "20140428144743+0100"
                                            },
                                            "high": {
                                                "nullFlavor": "UNK"
                                            },
                                            "text": "                                                          "
                                        },
                                        "value": {
                                            "codeSystemName": "ICD-9",
                                            "xsi:type": "CD",
                                            "code": "003.1",
                                            "displayName": "Sla sia",
                                            "codeSystem": "2.16.840.1.103",
                                            "originalText": {
                                                "reference": {
                                                    "value": "#pr101-desc"
                                                },
                                                "text": "                                          "
                                            },
                                            "text": "                                      "
                                        },
                                        "entryRelationship": {
                                            "typeCode": "REFR",
                                            "observation": {
                                                "moodCode": "EVN",
                                                "classCode": "OBS",
                                                "templateId": [{
                                                    "root": "2.16.840..1.50"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "root": "2.16.8410.20.1.57"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "root": "1.3.6.13.1.4.1.1"
                                                }],
                                                "code": {
                                                    "codeSystemName": "LOINC",
                                                    "code": "33999-4",
                                                    "displayName": "Status",
                                                    "codeSystem": "2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"
                                                },
                                                "statusCode": {
                                                    "code": "completed"
                                                },
                                                "value": {
                                                    "codeSystemName": " CT",
                                                    "xsi:type": "CE",
                                                    "code": "55563",
                                                    "displayName": "active",
                                                    "codeSystem": "2.16.8406.96"
                                                },
                                                "text": "                                                                                                                                                        "
                                            },
                                            "text": "                                      "
                                        },
                                        "text": "                                                                                                                                                                                  "
                                    },
                                    "text": "                              "
                                },
                                "text": "                                                                                                                            "
                            },
                            "text": "                      "
                        },
                        "text": "                                                          "
                    },
                    "text": "              "
                },
```

When i used get_json_object below mentioned data came up `null`.

```
"title": "problems",
                        "text": {
                            "mediaType": "text/x-hl7-text+xml",
                            "list": [{
                                "caption": "Recorded",
                                "item": {
                                    "ID": "pr101",
                                    "content": [{
                                        "ID": "pr101-desc",
                                        "text": "Salm"
                                    },
                                    "003.1"],
```

Comment: The provided JSON is not valid. There is a missing "{" at the beginning. A comma after "codeSystemName": "LOINC" and a comma at the very end. Use something like http://jsonlint.com/ to fix that first.

Comment: I might have missed it while i was manually editing (masking). Like i said this is not the full file, i just provided the one section for an example. So how i do drill down using Hive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated-you have to format your JSON file in such a way that each record should be in just one line, like

```
'{"section":{"moodCode":"xxx","classCode":"xxx","templateId":{"root":"2.xx.840"},"code":{"codeSystemName":"LOINC"},"title":"problems","text":{"mediaType":"text/x-hl7-text+xml","list":[{"caption":"Recorded","item":{"ID":"pr101","content":[{"ID":"pr101-desc","text":"Salm"},"003.1"],"text":"                                              "},"text":"                                        "},{"caption":"Reported","item":"None Reported","text":"                                        "}],"text":"                                  "},"entry":{"typeCode":"DRIV","act":{"moodCode":"EVN","classCode":"ACT","templateId":[{"root":"2.16.840.1.0.1.27"},{"root":"1.3.6.1.4..1"},{"root":"1.3.6.1.4.4.5.2"}],"id":{"root":"068fd4d4-dfa2-48190768f"},"code":{"nullFlavor":"NA"},"statusCode":{"code":"completed"},"effectiveTime":{"low":{"value":"20140428144743+0100"},"high":{"value":"20140428144743+0100"},"text":""},"entryRelationship":{"typeCode":"SUBJ","observation":{"moodCode":"EVN","classCode":"OBS","templateId":[{"root":"2.16.840.1.20.1.28"},{"root":"1.3.6.1.4.1.5.3.1.4.5"}],"id":{"root":"fa34b4da4dbb-b090-01bd4d6ef62b"},"code":{"codeSystemName":"SNOMEDCT","code":"282009","displayName":"diagnosis","codeSystem":"2.16.840.1.6.96"},"text":"","statusCode":{"code":"completed"},"effectiveTime":{"low":{"value":"20140428144743+0100"},"high":{"nullFlavor":"UNK"},"text":""},"value":{"codeSystemName":"ICD-9","xsi: type":"CD","code":"003.1","displayName":"Slasia","codeSystem":"2.16.840.1.103","originalText":{"reference":{"value":"#pr101-desc"},"text":""},"text":""},"entryRelationship":{"typeCode":"REFR","observation":{"moodCode":"EVN","classCode":"OBS","templateId":[{"root":"2.16.840..1.50"},{"root":"2.16.8410.20.1.57"},{"root":"1.3.6.13.1.4.1.1"}],"code":{"codeSystemName":"LOINC","code":"33999-4","displayName":"Status","codeSystem":"2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"},"statusCode":{"code":"completed"},"value":{"codeSystemName":"CT","xsi: type":"CE","code":"55563","displayName":"active","codeSystem":"2.16.8406.96"},"text":""},"text":""}},"text":""},"text":""},"text":""}},"text":""}'
```

Now create a table treating the entire string as one column

```
'drop table json_test;
create external table json_test(value string)
LOCATION 'path'; '
```

you can lateral view json_tuple to get the fields you need now.

```
'set hive.cli.print.header=true;
 SELECT c.moodCode,c.classCode,d.root,c.title,e.mediaType FROM json_test a  LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(a.value, 'section') b AS section LATERAL VIEW   json_tuple(b.section,'moodCode','classCode','templateId','title','text')c
 AS moodCode,classCode,templateId,title,text LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(c.templateId,'root')d
 AS root LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(c.text,'mediaType')e AS mediaType;'
```

result

```
'c.moodcode|c.classcode|d.root   |c.title |e.mediatype
   xxx     | xxx       |2.xx.840 |problems|text/x-hl7-text+xml'
```

Comment: Thanks much for taking time to reply, as i mentioned in my question the text part is

Comment: Thanks much for taking time to reply, please have a look at the json you have formatted "value in the text part is missing". I exactly face the same problem. If json is nested in-build UDFs doesn't recognise or pull the nested arrays. I copy pasted the data for your reference     '{"section":{"moodCode":"xxx","classCode":"xxx","templateId":{"root":"2.xx.840"},"code":{"codeSystemName":"LOINC"},"title":"problems","text"<<<<<DATA IS MISSING HERE>>>"","entry":{"typeCode":"DRIV","act":{"moodCode":"EVN","classCode":"ACT","templateId":[{"root":"2.16.840.1.0.1.27"},{"root":"1.3.6.1.4..1"}

Comment: @Ron thanks for pointing it out, For some reason, when i pasted your data in json validator it omitted the text part. I reformatted the data and ran the query. You data formatting has to be done properly, then the above query will work. Hope this answers your question.  you have to use this Lateral view because in built UDF's don't work with nested json's

Comment: Note: Please mark it as answered if this answered your question.